# Java uninstalled but still cannot install java 6 macOS

Tags: macos, java

I'm trying to install Java SE 6 because I need it to use Scilab, I follow [this](https://www.java.com/es/download/help/mac_uninstall_java.xml) and [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/mac_jdk.html#A1096903) tutorials for uninstall java, but still cannot install Java SE 6.

When I'm trying to install appears this message `You cannot install Java for macOS 2017-001 on this disk. A newer version of this package is already installed.`

The command `java -version` in terminal shows `No Java runtime present, requesting install.`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- First, try to download listed [Java](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US) and if that didn't go straightway, use the following script to install it.

Here is a simpler way, an AppleScript that removes the installation limits from Java for macOS 2017-001.

```
set theDMG to choose file with prompt "Please select javaforosx.dmg:" of type {"dmg"}
do shell script "hdiutil mount " & quoted form of POSIX path of theDMG
do shell script "pkgutil --expand /Volumes/Java\\ for\\ macOS\\ 2017-001/JavaForOSX.pkg ~/tmp"
do shell script "hdiutil unmount /Volumes/Java\\ for\\ macOS\\ 2017-001/"
do shell script "sed -i '' 's/return false/return true/g' ~/tmp/Distribution"
do shell script "pkgutil --flatten ~/tmp ~/Desktop/Java.pkg"
do shell script "rm -rf ~/tmp"
display dialog "Modified Java.pkg saved on desktop" buttons {"Ok"}
```

The script asks you to select the dmg file, opens the file, unpacks JavaForOSX.pkg, modifies the Distribution file and saves a new pkg file on Desktop, Java.pkg, that can be installed on Catalina.

---

For those who prefer doing this directly in Terminal:

```
t=${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/java
hdiutil mount /path/to/javaforosx.dmg
pkgutil --expand /Volumes/Java\ for\ macOS\ 2017-001/JavaForOSX.pkg "$t"
hdiutil unmount /Volumes/Java\ for\ macOS\ 2017-001
sed -i '' 's/return false/return true/g' "$t"/Distribution
pkgutil --flatten "$t" ~/Desktop/Java.pkg
rm -rf "$t"
open ~/Desktop/Java.pkg
```

Comment: I've added a shell version for those who don't want to go via AppleScript

Comment: That answer for terminal is pretty amazing. Just threw all that into a `.sh` file and it worked. Nice one.

Answer (score 2):

there is another possibility to make Scilab work on Catalina: install an OpenJDK such the ones available at https://adoptopenjdk.net/. These JDK will allow Scilab to start on Catalina out of the box, unlike JDK from Oracle which are not AppBundle and JNI aware.